# Удаление элементов с одинаковыми значениями в Map'е (Kotlin)

Tags: сортировка, kotlin, map

Новичок в Котлин, прошу помочь 
Дан ассоциативный массив (map) вида :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно превратить его в такой вид :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Ваши попытки? В чём вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сходу вот так может быть.

```
val map1 = mapOf(1 to 'a', 2 to 'a' , 3 to 'b', 4 to 'c', 5 to 'd', 6 to 'd')
val map2 = map1.filterValues { v -> map1.count { it.value == v} == 1}
println(map1) // {1=a, 2=a, 3=b, 4=c, 5=d, 6=d}
println(map2) // {3=b, 4=c}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/Cy327v0MW

Comment: Спасибо огромное)